# Sql right outer join ignore all null rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Old SQL query

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(ColValue1), 0.00) AS Rejection 
FROM 
    Tabel1 a, Table2 b, Table3 c 
WHERE 
    b.col1 =* a.col2 
    AND c.col1 = a.col3 
    AND b.colx = 'xxxxxxx' 
    AND YEAR(TDate) = 2017 
    AND MONTH(TDate) = 11 
GROUP BY 
    c.columnz 
ORDER BY 
    c.columnZ
```

This returns 15 rows based on c.columnz:

```
Rejection   
-----------
0.02897429    
0.02215681      
0.00000000    
0.00000000    
0.00000000    
0.58119017   
0.24542928   
1.17601530    
1.41633147  
0.00000000   
0.00000000  
0.51131100    
0.00000000    
1.10613613   
0.09033161
```

After I converted the query to SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(SUM(ColValue1), 0.00) AS Rejection 
FROM
    Table2 b  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    Tabel1 a ON b.col1 = a.col2
    ,Table3 c 
WHERE 
    c.col1 = a.col3 
    AND b.colx = 'xxxxxxx' 
    AND YEAR(TDate) = 2017 
    AND MONTH(TDate) = 11 
GROUP BY 
    c.columnz 
ORDER BY 
    c.columnZ
```

The query only returns 9 rows (ignored all null rows)

```
Rejection    
----------
0.02897429   
0.02215681    
0.58119017   
0.24542928   
1.17601530   
1.41633147   
0.51131100   
1.10613613   
0.09033161
```

Please help me fix the new query and get it to return all 15 rows.

All three tables and columns

```
SELECT
    [REJ_CODE], [REJ_GROUPING], [TYPE]
FROM 
    [QAApr2006].[dbo].[Reject_Group];

SELECT
    [REJ_RKEY], [REJECT_CODE], 
    [REJECT_DESCRIPTION], [REJECT_ABBRV]
FROM
    [QAApr2006].[dbo].[Reject_Code];

SELECT
    [PR_GRP_CODE], [PROD_CODE],
    [CUSTOMER_PART_DESC], [TDATE],
    [REJ_CODE], [REJ_PARTS], [REJ_M2],
    [P_TYPE], [WO_Number],
    [REJ_CODE_ABBRV], [REJECT_DESCRIPTION]
FROM 
    [QAApr2006].[dbo].[QA_Rej_Det1];
```

Comment: It depends on where ColValue1 and TDate  belong to. Please specify aliases in the query. BTW, Oracle old join syntax is =+ .

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit (comma separated) joins.

Comment: Please don't bury like the real query in comments, and PLEASE do NOT use a single row to carry your whole query. Format it so we can read it without left/right scrolling.

Comment: It was giving me some missing column aliases that made "try 2" possible, do always include them in your sql code. *& do please delete your "answer"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### try 2

in a comment below *"c. REJ_GROUPING has 15 rows and b.[Tdate]"* so I upended the query as follows:

```
SELECT
      ISNULL(SUM(REJ_M2), 0.00) AS rejection
FROM [QAApr2006].[dbo].Reject_Group c
LEFT JOIN [QAApr2006].[dbo].Reject_Code a ON c.REJ_CODE = a.REJECT_CODE
LEFT JOIN [QAApr2006].[dbo].QA_Rej_Det1 b ON a.REJ_RKEY = b.REJ_CODE
            AND b.CUSTOMER_PART_DESC = '0115761002'
            AND b.[Tdate] >= '20171101'
            AND b.[Tdate] < '20171201'
GROUP BY
      c.REJ_GROUPING
ORDER BY
      c.REJ_GROUPING
```

It worked (although the confirming comment was added elsewhere).

---

original:
The alias b is used in the `where clause` so it is most likely to be the table we use first in the `from clause` so the outer joins now are left joins.

```
SELECT
      ISNULL(SUM(REJ_M2), 0.00) AS rejection
FROM [QAApr2006].[dbo].QA_Rej_Det1 b
LEFT JOIN [QAApr2006].[dbo].Reject_Code a ON b.REJ_CODE = a.REJ_RKEY
LEFT JOIN [QAApr2006].[dbo].Reject_Group c ON a.REJECT_CODE = c.REJ_CODE
WHERE b.CUSTOMER_PART_DESC = '0115761002'
AND TDate >= '20171101'
AND TDate < '20171201'
GROUP BY
      REJ_GROUPING
ORDER BY
      Rej_Grouping
```

There is simply no good reason to use YEAR() and MONTH() to achieve an accurate date range filter, just nominate the 1st date of the month you want, and the 1st of the next month.

The other thing this query seriously suffers from is that `REJ_M2`,`REJ_GROUPING` and `Tdate` have no table aliases, so I really have no idea if the left joins are effective or not. Reference **EVER** column with the table aliases (or table names if aliases aren't supplied).

### ----

*As a personal note I really detest aliases that indicate sequence in a query (a,b,c...) because if we need to re-sequence all of a sudden those aliases are really painful. I prefer "first letter" or "first-letter-of-each-word" as the aliases method,* e.g.

```
SELECT
      ISNULL(SUM(rc.REJ_M2), 0.00) AS rejection
FROM [QAApr2006].[dbo].QA_Rej_Det1 q
LEFT JOIN [QAApr2006].[dbo].Reject_Code rc ON q.REJ_CODE = rc.REJ_RKEY
LEFT JOIN [QAApr2006].[dbo].Reject_Group rg ON rc.REJECT_CODE = rg.REJ_CODE
WHERE q.CUSTOMER_PART_DESC = '0115761002'
AND q.TDate >= '20171101'
AND q.TDate < '20171201'
GROUP BY
      q.REJ_GROUPING
ORDER BY
      q.Rej_Grouping
```

This variant may not work because the column aliases are just guesses, & I'm not fixing that.

Comment: Thanks Bro, it still returns 9 rows only (ignored null rows) .c. REJ_GROUPING has 15 rows and b.[Tdate]